# Change the font of a document in XelaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

So I downloaded a template for a CV. It uses XeLaTeX. I would like to change the font but I lost hope to find myself how I am supposed to do that. My OS is Windows 7. Here is a functional code that uses the original font Fontin. I downloaded it to make it work, and I would like to use something else (and something that uses accents (I speak french) !)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} 

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{} % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt} % Spacing around sections
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
\setmarginsrb{25mm}{0mm}{30mm}{0mm}{1cm}{5mm}{1mm}{10mm}
\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section

\par{\Huge TacTac \textsc{TicToc} - OncheOnche \bigskip\par} 
\par{\Huge \hspace{8mm}  huehuehue \bigskip\par}

\section{Données personnelles}
\begin{textblock}{.9}(0,0)
\rule{97mm}{0.09mm}
\end{textblock}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Date de naissance:} & 01 brumeneige 3030 \\
\textsc{Adresse:} & Somewhere, sometimes \\
\textsc{Téléphone:} & +123456789\\
\textsc{Email:} & what about
\end{tabular}


\section{Objectifs}\titlerule

I met a traveler from an antic land who said : Two vast and trunkless legs of stone stand in the desert... \\

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                      ---------



\end{document}
```

I believe the problem comes from the lines

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
```

But I don't know what I must change, where does the compiler look for the fonts...
I saw other questions that look like mine, but all used Linux. I also saw that there could be some problems with fonts using spaces in their name (seriously...?)... Anyway. Someone got an idea ?

Comment: Welcome! Well, Fontin is the name of the font. If you want to use a different one, use a different name. Which fonts depend on which fonts are installed on you system. Any truetype or opentype font should work. See the `fontspec` manual for details. By the way, this is not a good template.  The fact that it uses `vmargin` is more than enough reason not to use it.

Comment: Your assumption is right. To change the main font from Fontin to something else, just change `\setmainfont{Fontin}` to `\setmainfont{Some other font}`. Also, it's a bad idea to just use someone else's template if you have no idea what it is doing. The first step should be to do a search for "xelatex" and "fontspec" in order to learn the basics.

Comment: I recommend avoiding `vmargin` and preferring `geometry`.

Comment: Got it, indeed I just need to change    \setmainfont{Fontin} to \setmainfont{Arial} or something. That's strange, I thought that I tried that and that didn't work... mmmh. Anyway, it works now. Even with CMU Serif !

Comment: How do I vote for the comment of @Sverre ? That is his comment that unlocked me..

Comment: @Darryl I can convert my comment into an answer, and then you can [accept it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852).

Comment: @Sverre Ok let's do this !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stripping down your document to the bare minimum required for this question (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for more detail), the following shows how to change the main font of your document with `\setmainfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % add nonsense text
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}

\usepackage{url,parskip} % Formatting packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors    
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}     

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright}{}{0em}{} % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt} % Spacing around sections
\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color

\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
    \setmarginsrb{25mm}{0mm}{30mm}{0mm}{1cm}{5mm}{1mm}{10mm}
    \pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

    \par{\Huge TacTac \textsc{TicToc} - OncheOnche \bigskip\par} 
    \par{\Huge \hspace{8mm}  huehuehue \bigskip\par}

    \section{Données personnelles}
    \begin{textblock}{.9}(0,0)
        \rule{97mm}{0.09mm}
    \end{textblock}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        \textsc{Date de naissance:} & 01 brumeneige 3030 \\
        \textsc{Adresse:} & Somewhere, sometimes \\
        \textsc{Téléphone:} & +123456789\\
        \textsc{Email:} & what about
    \end{tabular}

    \section{Objectifs}\titlerule

    I met a traveler from an antic land who said : Two vast and trunkless legs of stone stand in the desert... \\

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   EDUCATION
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                      ---------

\end{document}
```

[image]