# Sabon font in latex

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I do not have any file. I want to know each and every point how to set sabon as default font style in `LaTeX`

I want to use sabon but now  I am at zero point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
  \setsansfont{Arial}
  \setmonofont[Color={0019D4}]{Courier New}


\begin{document}
hkjhkjh 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are several fonts that claim to be an incarnation of `Sabon`. Which Sabon font is on your system?

Comment: Mico sir i do not know i just want sabon as default font in my latex file but i cannot kindly help me out

Comment: Do you have the commercial Sabon on your system?

Comment: @IQRARao - A statement such as "i just want sabon" is not helpful. I asked you earlier *which* Sabon font was present on your system. Until and unless you provide this piece of information, there is simply no way to provide specific advice. Incidentally, it would also be useful if you provided information about which operating system is installed on your computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the font of a document in XelaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257522/change-the-font-of-a-document-in-xelatex)

Answer (score 4):

This question is a more or less a duplicate of [Change the font of a document in XelaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257522/change-the-font-of-a-document-in-xelatex). I will answer it here in order to make the steps explicit, and then vote to close.

First, you need to find the font on your system. For Windows one way is to check the list of fonts in Microsoft Word, for example. You can also look up the fonts in the Explorer, see for example https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=50. For Mac there is an app called Font Book that shows your installed fonts. For Ubuntu there is the Fonts application in the Application menu. When you find the font you need to remember either the name of the font or the filename.

If you don't have the font that you want on your system then you can try to find the font online and install it on your system. Commercial fonts need to be bought and can sometimes be very expensive, but for many well-known fonts there are also freely available clones or variants. If you use a free font then check if it is legal, especially when you want to publish your document.

Then, in LaTeX, you specify the font that you want to use with the command `\setmainfont` from the `fontspec` package (XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX only), or one of the variants for particular styles, such as `\setsansfont` to specify which font you want to use for Sans Serif text. As argument to `\setmainfont` you can use either the font name, or the filename.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sabon Next.ttf}

\begin{document}
Pa's wijze lynx bezag vroom het fikse aquaduct 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that in this MWE I used the filename, with the extension `.ttf`. I found this font online.

The sentence is the Dutch variant of the famous 'the quick brown fox' sentence, and translates to "Dad's wise lynx looked piously over the large aquaduct".